Audio en HTML sin Controls
espero alguien me pueda ayudar, quiero poner un audio usando html y que al cargar la pagina se reproduzca automáticamente pero sin que aparezcan los controles. ¿Alguien me puede decir como hacerlo? les dejo el código que estaba usando... nota: lo estoy haciendo en block de notas.
<audio autoplay loop>
<source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>


No se puede. Hace muchos años era común los banners con música (papamericando ), a causa de esto los navegadores implementaron medidas para evitar este comportamiento. Hoy, el sonido puede activarse solo si el usuario ha interactuado con la página (un click por ejemplo)
